# Possible lossy conversion from double to int and cannot find symbol

Tags: java, int, double

I'm getting an error in my program saying:

> Lyrics.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
>
> ```
>  Cube(b);
>  ^
> ```
>
> symbol:   method Cube(int)
>
> location: class Lyrics
>
> Lyrics.java:15: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
>
> ```
>  return Math.pow (b, 3);
>                    ^
> ```
>
> 2 errors

I looked around on the website and it turns out other people also had this issue but i looked at the comments and i still dont understand the problem, theres no double in my code why would it say this. And i also dont undestand the error saying cannot find symbol. Please help ive really been stuck on this for a while.

```
  import static java.lang.Math.pow;
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class Lyrics
  {
       public static void main(String []args)
       {
            int b;
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println ("Enter a number: ");
            b = scan.nextInt();
            Cube(b);
       }
       public static int cube (int b)
       {
            return Math.pow (b, 3);
       }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, but do you understand the other error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first problem is a simple typo.  Java is case sensitive, so `cube` and `Cube` mean different things.  Solution: 1) be consistent, and 2) use names starting with lowercase letters for method names ... as per the Java style guides.

---

The second problem is due to the method signature for `Math.pow`; see the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow-double-double-).  It returns the result as a `double`.  You then attempte to return the `double` as an `int`, and *that* is a lossy conversion.

The solutions include:

```
  return b * b * b;   // i.e. don't use `pow`.
```

or

```
  return (int) Math.pow(b, 3);
```

The second one directly addresses your compilation error by *casting* the `double` return to an `int`.  This is the way you tell the compiler that the lossy conversion is actually OK.

The lossy conversion error message you are seeing refers to that fact for large enough values of `b`, the result of `Math.pow(b, 3)` will be too large to be represented as an `int`<sup>1</sup>.  With the type cast in place, Java will convert a floating point number that is "too large" into `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

The first solution is faster and simpler code, but if `b` is too large, the calculations will silently overflow and you will get a nonsense answer.

---

**UPDATE** - If you wanted overflow to always be treated as an error then:

```
return Math.multiplyExact(b, Math.multiplyExact(b, b));
```

or

```
return Math.toIntExact((long) Math.pow(b, 3));
```

or variations on the above.

---

<sup>1 - Actually, the compiler doesn't know about the semantics of `pow`, so it doesn't know about *"... for large enough values of `b` ..."*.  But it does know that if the method call *did* return a large enough value, then the conversion *would* be lossy.  That's why the message says *"**possible** lossy conversion"*.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

1. Letter case is important: `Cube` is not the same as `cube`.
2. Your function `cube(int)` returns an integer, but the output of `Math.pow` is a `double`.

You should probably change `cube()` to return a `double`.

Then you have more code to write in the `main` method to use the results of calling `cube`.